# Using FourSquare API in a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, foursquare

Anybody have any good resources that might be helpful in trying to integrate the FourSquare API into a Rails app?  I'm specifically looking for a good tutorial.  There doesn't seem to be much out there yet.  There are a few ruby gems, but they are pretty bare bones and I need a bit more hand-holding.

Here is a resource that I've found so far:
http://tedgrubb.com/

Stack Overflow won't let me include a second hyperlink, but you can also google: Foursquare ruby gem for another resource.

I have not done much work with APIs in the past, but I am very comfortable with Rails.  What I need is a little better sense of exactly where all the pieces fit.  A basic tutorial is what I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This helped me. It's a working example of a Rails project integrated with FourSquare:
https://github.com/pierrevalade/foursquare-rails-examples

Answer (score 1):

Quimby is an excellent ruby api wrapper:

https://github.com/groupme/quimby

It was built by GroupMe.

Answer (score 1):

'foursquare2' Ruby wrapper for the foursquare v2 API

Refere this : https://github.com/mattmueller/foursquare2 which is good & helped me a lot.

You can able to get more foursquare API data as user less and with authenticated user also 
by using the 'foursquare2' gem.

Comment: As old as this is, it deserves the answer.

Basically, Foursquare2 hits and handles all and any available endpoints quite well, even to today. It's flexible enough to include the api date tagging which is required now as well. I've used it a bunch - never felt lost since the gem docs literally say "read the foursquare docs". Anything you can use in PHP, etc still applies to this gem. It's a huge winner.

Answer (score 0):

The [foursquare-API](https://github.com/ronaldwan/foursquare-api) gem seems like the only one out there that supports V2 of their API and seems like the best place to start.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't an answer, but this may be a start:

http://stakeventures.com/articles/2009/07/21/consuming-oauth-intelligently-in-rails
http://developer.foursquare.com/docs/oauth.html

I'm having trouble implementing a 4sq rails app myself.